# VBA to move a cell content and delete the row - introduce error checking

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have written the following lines of code in VBA and I'm new to VBA.

```vbs
Sub move_content()
'declaration
    Dim srcrow, srccol, destrow, destcol As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Long

'intialization
    srcrow = 4 ' source row
    srccol = 7 ' source column
    destrow = 3 ' destination row
    destcol = 8 ' destination column

'finding out the last row in the data - Column G has the data
    lastrow = Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastrow
'Cut the contents of the source cell
        Cells(srcrow, srccol).Select
        Selection.Cut

'paste the contents in destination cell
        Cells(destrow, destcol).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

'Delete the entire row after the cut-paste operation
        Rows(srcrow).EntireRow.Delete

        srcrow = srcrow + 1
' If the next source cell is blank exit for loop
        If Cells(srcrow, srccol).Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If

        destrow = destrow + 1
        i = i + 1

    Next
End Sub
```

I remember someone telling me that I should include error checking in my routines. I don't understand what I need to do.

*Note: The code executes and it does what it is intended to do*

Comment: why is my code not in color code? even though I added the `<!-- language: lang-vbs -->` in the beginning of my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error handling in VBA is, unfortunately, not as graceful as it could be. Where most languages throw exceptions that can be caught using `try` ... `catch` blocks, VBA doesn't have anything quite so graceful.

Looking over your code, there aren't a lot of points of failure, so you may not need to worry too much about error handling. However, error handling can be approached in one of two ways:

```
On Error Goto LABEL/LINE
```

or

```
On Error Resume Next
```

---

`On Error Goto ...` functions by jumping to a specified label or line number. For example:

```
Sub move_content()
    On Error Goto errhandler
    'declaration
        Dim srcrow, srccol, destrow, destcol As Integer
        Dim lastrow As Long
    ...
    ...
    Exit Sub
errhandler:
    Msg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " _
        & Err.Source & Chr(13) & Err.Description
    MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.Helpfile, Err.HelpContext
End Sub
```

Should an error occur, it would jump to your error handler and, in this instance, show a message box of the error without breaking the debugger.

`On Error Resume Next` does exactly what it says - if an error is thrown on a line, it simply skips it and carries on. Depending on what you're trying to achieve, this behaviour could be useful, for instance, if you simply want to check if something exists in array, you could return `true` if it does, and `false` if an error is thrown.

To make this error handling useful, really you need to abstract different parts of it into smaller subs so you can correctly handle each type of error.

---

In terms of simply checking for errors, usually `IF .. THEN` statements can be used to check that values entered as as expected by the script. For example, you may want to have an `IF ... THEN` to make sure the srccol, srcrow, destcol and destrow are all above 0, to be valid. A simple check such as:

```
'intialization
    srcrow = 4 ' source row
    srccol = 7 ' source column
    destrow = 3 ' destination row
    destcol = 8 ' destination column

If srcrow <= 0 OR srccol <= 0 OR destrow <= 0 OR destcol <= 0 Then
    Msgbox "Invalid row or column number (Less than or equal to zero!)"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

would make sure no mistakes had been made before trying to execute and potentially raising an error to be handled.

---

On a side note with your code, you don't need to cut and paste, you can simply do something like:

```
Cells(destrow, destcol) = Cells(srcrow, srccol)
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- [On Error Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266173(v=vs.60).aspx)
- [Err Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka13cy19(v=vs.90).aspx)